# amazon boto3:run-instance with --user-data flag has no effect on newly created instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I'm facing an issue where providing user-data flag has no effect whatsoever using `boto3` api as opposed to `awscli` which works perfectly fine.

the user-data file holds raw bash commands(no base64encode)

Working Sample:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --user-data "file://C:\Users\koko\PycharmProjects\AWS\test.txt" --image-id ami-9abea4fb --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name KEY --security-group-ids "SomeKey" --region us-west-2
```

and here's the non-working boto3 sample:

```
 res = client.run_instances(
            ImageId=imageId,
            InstanceType=instanceType,
            MinCount=count,
            MaxCount=count,
            SecurityGroupIds=securityGroupId.split(),
            UserData='file://C:\\Users\\koko\\PycharmProjects\\AWS\\userdata.cfg',
            KeyName=keyName)
```

Both commands are executed successfully according to the returned json + instances are actually created.

In addition, i also tried to compare the user-data field from amazon's GUI, and they both were identical.

EDIT: when i view user-data's contents of all instances generated by boto3, i see file's path, as provided to the script, opposed to the aws-cli which has the actual script expended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UserData` parameter is a **string**, the contents of which becomes the User Data.

While the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) allows you to specify a file as input, boto3 does not.

Your app will need to **read the contents of the file**, then pass the contents as a string to the `run_instances()` function.